# Adding a tag to an entity in spaCy's displaCy named entity visualizer

Tags: spacy

Is there a way to use spaCy's **displaCy Named Entity Visualizer** and add an additional term after the entity's type?  Our application tries to link each entity mention to a Wikidata item.  We'd like to include a Wikidata QID after the type if one is found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question is clear as-is if you're familiar with the library. If you aren't the docs here should clarify things. https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#ent

Answer (score 0):

No, the Named Entity Visualizer doesn't support that.

It's a pretty recent feature but I believe the [span visualizer](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#span) can do what you want. You should save your WikiData IDs using the `kb_id` property on spans, similar to how the [Entity Linker](https://spacy.io/api/entitylinker/#_title) works, and then you can add links directly.